# Unable to list "all" class text from a webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to list all nickname from a specific forum thread (webpage)

```
url = "https://www.webpage.com"
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
 
username = doc.find('div', class_='userText')
userd = username.a.text
print(userd)
```

On the webpage:

```
 <div class="userText">
      <a href="profil/user/" class="username" itemprop="name">Nickname1</a>
    </div>
      <a href="profil/user/" class="username" itemprop="name">Nickname2</a>
    </div>
  etc
```

So I'm sucessfully isolating the "userText" name from the webpage.
The thing is that I'm only able to get the frist nickname while there is more than 150 inside the page.

I tried a

```
doc.find_all
```

instead of my

```
doc.find
```

But then I'm hit with a

> You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I'm unsure on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with a loop + put the div inside a list

```
username = doc.find_all(["div"], class_="userText")
for i in range(0,150):
    print(username[i].a.text)
```